# How to store a binary search tree into a two-d array and print it out, in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-tree

I already create a binary search tree, but I don't know how to put it into a two-d array (I am interested in both recursion way and non-recursion way) and print it out.

As the picture below

```
           7
         /   \
        5     9
       / \   / \
      4   6 8  15
      .
      .
      .
```

Sorry for the vague expression. Basically I was trying to 
1) read the sequences of numbers from the file and build a binary search tree for them.

2) I need to plot the tree into the character array(must be 2-D array) to represent the the drawing area. So the root of the tree must be in the middle of the first row of the array, and the first left child must be in the middle of the half part of the second row, and the first right child must be in the middle of another half part of the second row. and so on.

as the graph below

```
------------34------------

-----24------------56-----

---9-----32-----41----57--
```

3)finally I need to print it out(as the first graph).

I have BinaryNode.class BinaryTree.class and inside the tree class,
there are several basic methods getmethod and setmethod for root, left child and right child.

Here is part of my code on main class:

```
BinaryTree BinarySearchTree = new BinaryTree();

 FileReader theFile;

 BufferedReader inFile;

 String oneLine;

 try{

   theFile = new FileReader(args[0]);

   inFile = new BufferedReader(theFile);

   while((oneLine = inFile.readLine())!= null){

    String[] list = oneLine.split(",");

    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){                           

      BinaryNode TreeNode = new BinaryNode(list[i]);

      BinaryTree.insert(BinarySearchTree, TreeNode.element);

      }

      }

      }

      catch (Exception e) {

           System.out.println(e);

          }


    // building binary search tree

    public static BinaryTree insert(BinaryTree t, Object x){

      if(t.isEmpty())

      return new BinaryTree(x);

      else{

          if(((Integer)t.getRootobj()).intValue()<((Integer)x).intValue())

            t.setRight(insert(t.getRight(),x));

          else

            t.setLeft(insert(t.getLeft(),x));

            return t;

         }
```

Comment: Can we see some of the code you already have?

Comment: @halfer sure. thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the value of node as index in the first array and the values of the children to be stored the second array. You can put the value of the left child as index 0 and the value of the right child to be with index 1. To mark that there is no left or right child you can use negative value or zero. To know the initial root element you can search for the first element having an array with at least one element or you can think of way to store the root element somewhere. Definitely not the best option but should work.

Here is example:

```
[0] -> {0,0}
[1] -> {2,3}
[2] -> {4,5}
[3] -> {6,7}
[4] -> {0,0}
```

Answer (score 0):

As binary tree is the particular example of the Graph data structure, you can check the existent Graph representations, for instance, adjacency lists or adjacency matrix.

These links may be helpful:

- [Graph representation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544959/graph-representation-in-java)
- http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-represent-a-Graph-in-Java

Answer (score 0):

You can store a binary tree in a 1D array.

```
       1
     /   \
    2     3
   / \   / \
  4   5 6   7
```

The result array A is A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

The left child of a node i is given by `2*i + 1`, the right child is given by `2*i + 2`, first node is 0 indexed.

Exemple: left and right child of the 3rd node (index : 2)
left child : 2*i + 1 = 2*2+1 = 5, A[5] = 6, correct !
right child : 2*i + 2 = 2*2 + 2 = 6, A[6] = 7, correct too !

So given this "algorithm" you can build a Java class that secretly handle the Tree in a 1D array !

Comment: I need to story it in a 2-D array > <